Problems with fixed effects model in R
I have an issue with a fixed effects model for analysing panel data in R, where I get results that I cannot explain to myself.
What am I trying to do?
I am trying to analyse the effect of the EU emissions price on the free cashflow to firms with several firm specific and macro economic control variables.
What data do I have?
I have a dataset from 2005 to 2022, balanced, with emissions and financial data for around 500 firms. In addition I have some macro data (one observation per year).
What model am I using?
I am using a fixed effects model (one-way and within).
What is the exact issue?
The results I get (see below) show that quite a few variables are insignificant, which is weird to me as for example GDP growth cannot be insignificant logically. Therefore, I am wondering whether I have used the wrong model, wrongly specified it, or missed doing some other things? I have tried to transform the variables by standardization, differencing, and also log transformation, which did not help and rather did the opposite.
Does anyone of you have an idea, what I did wrong or what I could do? Any help is greatly appreciated! :)
Output:
Call:
plm(formula = FCFF ~ GDP_Growth + INTANGIBLE_ASSETS + REVENUE +
DEPRECIATION + TOTAL_ASSETS + Patents_Filed + Exchange_Rate_EUR.CNY +
Inflation + Oil_Price + Lead_Spot + EU_ETS_Future + EU_ETS_Spot,
data = data, model = "within")
Balanced Panel: n = 511, T = 18, N = 9198
Residuals:
Min.    1st Qu.     Median    3rd Qu.       Max.
-5609351.5    -5784.3     -676.8     3676.6  7938700.2
Coefficients:
Estimate  Std. Error  t-value  Pr(>|t|)
GDP_Growth             6.6277e+02  2.9418e+03   0.2253  0.821758
INTANGIBLE_ASSETS     -1.4629e-01  2.1718e-02  -6.7356 1.736e-11 ***
REVENUE                1.2738e-01  3.2075e-03  39.7133 < 2.2e-16 ***
DEPRECIATION          -6.5236e-02  3.3733e-02  -1.9339  0.053159 .
TOTAL_ASSETS          -3.1834e-02  1.3248e-03 -24.0293 < 2.2e-16 ***
Patents_Filed          8.6320e+02  6.4741e+02   1.3333  0.182460
Exchange_Rate_EUR.CNY  4.4507e+03  4.8599e+03   0.9158  0.359801
Inflation              2.3669e+03  5.3924e+03   0.4389  0.660724
Oil_Price             -6.7954e+01  1.5540e+02  -0.4373  0.661924
Lead_Spot             -4.3747e+02  3.5608e+02  -1.2286  0.219263
EU_ETS_Future         -7.9668e+03  3.2396e+03  -2.4592  0.013944 *
EU_ETS_Spot            7.8936e+03  3.0386e+03   2.5978  0.009398 **
Signif. codes:  0 ‘’ 0.001 ‘’ 0.01 ‘’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Total Sum of Squares:    3.5016e+14
Residual Sum of Squares: 2.8466e+14
R-Squared:      0.18705
Adj. R-Squared: 0.13814
F-statistic: 166.339 on 12 and 8675 DF, p-value: < 2.22e-16
